# How to make these n methods to a single generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class like this:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
  public string ErrorMessage { set;get;}
}
```

And some child classes which inherit from this:

```
public class Person:BaseResponse
{
  public string FirstNAme { set;get;}
}

public class Phone:BaseResponse
{
  public string SerialNumber { set;get;}
}

public class Car :BaseResponse
{
  public string Year{ set;get;}
}
```

Now I want to set the `ErrorMessage` property of each instance of this class to a different value. Currently this is what I am doing:

```
public Phone GetPhoneError(Phone objPhone)
{
  objPhone.ErrorMessage="Err msg related to Phone";
  return objPhone;
}

public Person GetPersonError(Person objPerson )
{
  objPerson .ErrorMessage="Err msg related to Person";
  return objPerson ;
}

... another similar method for Car also
```

Is there any way I can make this method a generic format so that I don't need 3 separate methods for setting the error message?

Comment: Why is a method called `Get...Error` *setting* the error?

Comment: Maybe use a virtual method on the base class? Override as needed. Set this.ErrorMessage instead.

Comment: If you are wanting a generic way of each class which inherits `BaseResponse` having its own *named* method then no, I don't believe you will be able to do that generically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public T GetError<T>(T obj) where T: BaseResponse
{
  obj.ErrorMessage= string.Format("Err msg related to {0}", typeof(T).Name);
  return obj;
}
```

I don't know if the error message is this generic thing or something custom. If so, then pass the message as an argument.

Why do you need a method for this? Is it because you have simplified the question?

Comment: Thanks. +1 .This is waht i was looking for. Sorry my question was little confusing

Answer (score 2):

So in your base class you should create a virtual method called SetError (your GetError but with the correct notation).

```
public abstract string GetErrorMessage(); //In Base Class so that why each implementation will set the correct error message
```

Then in your base class - also why do you need to return the same object that you are modifying?

```
public virtual void SetErrorMessage()
{
   this.ErrorMessage = GetErrorMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have a generic method like so:

```
public object GetError(BaseResponse response)
{
   response.ErrorMessage = "whatever";
   return response;
}
```

Comment: But i have to CAST it back to the original type wherever i call this. Any other options ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to handle that without a CAST when you pull it back out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make property `virtual` and no need for `set` in that case ? :

```
public class BaseResponse
{
  public virtual string ErrorMessage { get;}
}


public class Person:BaseResponse
{
  .....
  public override string ErrorMessage {get { return "Err msg related to Person";}}
}


public class Phone:BaseResponse
{
  ......
  public override string ErrorMessage {get { return "Err msg related to Phone";}}
}
```

and so on for others....